# Cannot read input file for image in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image

Here is my code:

```
BufferedImage downArrow;
BufferedImage downLeftArrow;
BufferedImage downRightArrow;
BufferedImage leftArrow;
BufferedImage rightArrow;
BufferedImage upArrow;
BufferedImage upLeftArrow;
BufferedImage upRightArrow;
public DirectionPanel()
{

    try{
         downArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/downArrow.png")));
         downLeftArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/downLeftArrow.png")));
         downRightArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/downRight.png")));
         leftArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/leftArrow.png")));
         rightArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/rightArrow.png")));
         upArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/upArrow.png")));
         upLeftArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/upLeftArrow.png")));
         upRightArrow = ImageIO.read(new File(("images/upRightArrow.png")));
    }catch(IOException whoops){
        System.out.println(whoops);
    }
}
```

It works in the compiler, but when I try to run it, it says "javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!"

Here is my file system:

```
Project

|

|____src

      |

      |____MapData

              |

              |____file

|

|____images

        |

        |____downArrow.png

        |

        |____downLeftArrow.png

        |

        |____etc.
```

What is going wrong? I tried to follow previous answers for this problem, and this is where I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to put your images in the resources folder (if you are working with an IDE).

Then use the ImageIO like this:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(DirectoryPanel.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/downArrow.png"));
```

Then the path he reads the image from is `<resources-root>/images/downArrow.png`. Otherwise the File path is relative to where your execution directory is.

Comment: I don't have a resources folder, but I think I am working with an IDE. If I were to make one, where would it be in the file system? This is what my file system currently looks like on my screen: http://i.imgur.com/XUCmtxB.png

Comment: Never mind - I got it to work. I now have a Resources "Source Folder" and within that I have an Images folder. From there, I can use your solution and it works! Thanks!